# What are the key differences between the versions of Blade: Trinity?

Tags: plot-explanation, alternate-version, blade-trinity

Having just watched the version of Blade Trinity currently on Netflix, I noticed some small differences with the original DVD release in my collection. Not least the ending was different (in the Netflix version autopsy scene Drake has substituted his body for Blade, in my memory Blade revives on the table and escapes). I also remember seeing more scenes between Drake and Danica.

[According to IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0359013/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0) there seem to be at least two alternate versions, but they were not very clear about the differences. I'm now confused about which version is on Netflix, which version I have on DVD and whether there are other versions I have not seen.

So, how many alternate versions are there and how do they differ?

Comment: If you had clicked on the [link](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0359013/alternateversions?tab=cz&ref_=tt_trv_alt) on the IMDB page, it would clearly state (some of) the major differences.

Comment: @Joachim as I said in the question *the IMDB page is confused and unclear* otherwise I would not have asked here. Is there some new ruling that alternate-version questions are no longer OK here?

Comment: Here's a report comparing the theatrical version and the extend version: https://www.movie-censorship.com/report.php?ID=2136

Comment: Oh no, that was not the implication. But it seems quite clear to me: there is a Theatrical Cut, and an Unrated Extended Edition, which features additional scenes with Danica and Drake and "a more ambiguous ending".